# how to change color smooth in scrolling snapping?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I learning coding HTML and CSS, I'm practicing this project on this website:https://backstagetalks.com/#issue5.
I'm wondering how can the background color of this website change so smoothly like that.

Answer (score 0):

#### Long story short

You need to change CSS transition property:

```
body{
  transition:background-color .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

This will animate/transition changing colors switched by "background-color" property.

If you are unsure of how the background color is changed you can do this:

```
body{
  transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

This will animate/transition everything

Answer (score 0):

You can use css [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) property

Check the `scrollTop` and change the `backgroundColor` when `scrollTop` reach some number

```js
const back = document.querySelector('.back')

back.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
  if (back.scrollTop >= 1000 && back.scrollTop < 2000) {
    back.style.backgroundColor = '#ffff00'
  } else if (back.scrollTop >= 2000 && back.scrollTop < 3000) {
    back.style.backgroundColor = '#00ff00'
  } else if (back.scrollTop >= 3000 && back.scrollTop < 4000) {
    back.style.backgroundColor = '#00ffff'
  } else if (back.scrollTop >= 4000 && back.scrollTop < 5000) {
    back.style.backgroundColor = '#0000ff'
  } else {
    back.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000'

  }
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.back {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  height: 296px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-in-out; /* Change 2s with delay */
}

.content {
  height: 5000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```